# Cloud Functions: using "where" query, can't get the docID Nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm using "where" query to get a single document so that I can update it. I need the docID which is what i'm struggling with. I'm following the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#node.js_2) but not much progress. I'm using Firebase cloud functions, Nodejs and Javascript.

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const firestore = admin.firestore();

exports.bucketTesting = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

//code to source file.metadata.mediaLink

  const imagesRef = firestore.collection("images");
  const specificImageRef = await imagesRef
    .where("imageUrl", "==", file.metadata.mediaLink)
    .get();
  console.log(specificImageRef);

  specificImageRef.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data());
  });
}
```

The `console.log(specificImageRef)` print data(that i can't use) but the `console.logs` in the forEach do not print anything.

How do I get the docID?

Comment: Are you sure that `specificImageRef` (which is a `QuerySnapshot`) contains documents? Can you do `console.log(specificImageRef.size)`?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec, ```Specific Image Size:  0```. This means that there are no documents, right? Just as you were saying. How do i get a document or the docID?

Comment: Look at my answer: "Your code is correct to get the document docID and data but as discussed in the above comments the query returns 0 documents".

Answer (score 0):

> Your comment: "How do i get a document or the docID?"

**Your code is correct to get the document docID and data but as discussed in the comments the query returns 0 documents.**

The only adaptation you could do since you are sure that there is only one document corresponding to the query is to use the `docs` array as follows:

```
exports.bucketTesting = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

  const imagesRef = firestore.collection("images");
  const querySnapshot = await imagesRef
          .where("imageUrl", "==", file.metadata.mediaLink)
          .get();

  if (querySnapshot.size === 0) {
     // No document found
     // Send back a message or an error
     res.status(500).send("No document found");
  } else {
     const uniqueDocSnapshot = querySnapshot.docs[0];
     console.log(uniqueDocSnapshot.id, "=>", uniqueDocSnapshot.data());

     res.send(...);
  }

        


})
```

Comment: I get the following error ```Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')``` and ```Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')```. Is it not because we are reading from a document size of 0 as shown in above comments?

Comment: If your query returns 0 documents it is normal that `querySnapshot.docs[0]` is undefined.

Comment: So that means that my query is not matching with any document/s in the collection?

Comment: yes that's it. I'll adapt my answer to show how to deal with that, i.e. sending back an error to the caller

Answer (score 0):

```js
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const firestore = admin.firestore();

exports.bucketTesting = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

  //code to source file.metadata.mediaLink

  const imagesRef = firestore.collection("images");
  
  // the following will return an array 
  const specificImages = (await imagesRef
    .where("imageUrl", "==", file.metadata.mediaLink)
    .get()).docs.map(each => each.data()) || [];
    
    
  /* the console log on the next line will show the array
  it will show multiple items if there is more than one document
  where imageUrl === file.metadata.mediaLink */
  console.log(specificImages);
  
  /* all is left to do is to return the array 
    or return a single document */
    
  // the following is the case when you are just returning a single document
  res.send({
    desiredData: specificImages?.[0] ?? {} // fallback if there is no document
  })
}
```

Comment: ```Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')``` is the error i get after removing the option of empty array(```|| []```).

Comment: Can you console log `await imagesRef.where("imageUrl", "==", file.metadata.mediaLink).get()`? do you see array of the snapshots ?